# Should vaccination be based on a principle of broad and rather unspecific immunization?

Tags: immunology, virology, coronavirus, vaccination

In the context of Covid-19, in Denmark all ferrets/minks in farms were killed, as there is infection in humans by virus from ferret.

Thus, a  virus transferred from ferret to man proves to find the same type of target cells.  This corresponds to  Jenner's vaccination (vacca means cow) against Small pox by transferring  cowpox virus from cow to man in so  far as cow pox virus does replicate in man if to a lesser degree, not causing disease.  The diffence between infection of man by CoV from ferret/minks  seems to lie in  "attenuation". Different to cow pox (that is named different from small pox)  CoV from ferret is dangerous to man to no lesser degree.

Still,  "attenuation" may not be the working mechanism that Jenner's vaccination was based on, as target cells not being infected in man in the same way as they are in  cow  must carry different antigen. Antigens of small pox are not identical to those of cow pox.

Jenner's technique seems to be unique in its use of a different type of virus: cow pox is different from small pox. In contrast, for example, live measles vaccine is not different from live measles virus.

Whereas live measle vaccine, e.g., uses the identical antigen, Jenner's vaccination apparently did not: Cow pox isn't small pox.

Hence, a principle of identity of antigen together with attenuation (live vaccine and others) can be distinguished from vaccination (Jenner) that found some so called cross-reactivity.  Difference of target antigen equals difference of antibody and t-cell specifity.

So, instead of using attenuation as a working principle, should we look for good cross-reactivity like Jenner did when developing vaccines?

The results of the following study   seems to be  in line with presumed  principle of non-identity and   unspecific immunization ("Jenner's"):

[Jacob Schön, Wei Ran et al.](https://www.nature.com/articles/s41541-020-0185-6), A modified live bat influenza A virus-based vaccine prototype provides full protection against HPAIV H5N1, May 15, 2020.

Considering that according to this finding there exists flu virus from bat that is not pathogenic in other animal species, yet valid vaccine in other species, the question may be rephrased as follows: If there is no harmful infection of a  different species/different kind of target cells found in a different species, how can such non-pathogenic virus antigen lead to immunization against disease? The finding above contradicts any principle of specifity of immunization; how to explain?

Some other reference says:
"... In contrast, viruses of the recently identified bat-borne IAV subtypes H17N10 and H18N11 encode HA and NA homologs unable to interact with sialic acid residues despite a high degree of structural homology with their conventional counterparts...",  see [Ciminski/Martin Schwemmle, 2019, Bat-Borne Influenza A Viruses: An Awakening, 2019](http://perspectivesinmedicine.cshlp.org/content/11/2/a038612)

If the mechanism of vaccination were identity of antigen and  attenuation any immunization induced by "homologs unable to interact" (with target cells) should not be of any help against infection by "conventional counterparts" (as there is no identity of antigen, thus antibodies/t cell receptor).

Comment: You're talking about completely different things, and it's not at all clear (especially after reading your self-answer) that you have any idea what you're talking about. Vaccinia and variola are two entirely separate species, while both the mink and human SARS-CoV-2 viruses are just different subtypes of the same virus. Just because Vaccinia (usually) causes a sub-lethal and eventually protective infection in humans doesn't mean anything of the sort is going on with the mink and human SARS-CoV-2 variants. Jenner was extremely lucky.

Comment: "self-answer" is pejorative for "jeopardy question and answer style share your wisdom - did I choose the wrong form, it's encouraged to answer your own question.

Comment: To MatDMO: what you're explaining contentwise suits me well That's my very question, if vaccinia virus and variola virus are or are not different in respect of immunity, and to what extent exactly. as they quite strikingly  induce  "cross-reactive" immunity!  If you only told me what exactly the difference is between variola and vaccinia is  that could be the start of a great affinity (of ours, smile).However, "Jenner was just lucky" does in fact answer my question, in the negative and according to common wisdom and perspective.

Comment: Hint: to reply to someone's comment, simply use the @username convention. I would be `@MattDMo`, for instance. As you type, an autocomplete box will pop up, so you don't have to type out the whole thing. The reason I'm not pinging you in this comment is because you are the original poster (OP), and so are notified of all comments in this area. In comments under answers. you would be pinged if someone @ mentions you.

Comment: @MattDMo, thank you, so this is addressing you correctly? I do not understand why my self-answer has been deleted by Chris. without comment, not by you.  I will constantly enhance my question. Currently, it's focus on "attenuation". You say Jenner was lucky, I agree (by the way, allegedly  Jenner's vaccine had been used by the Chinese much ealier) - my question refers to the possibility that modern"er" (kind of German, it's my mother tongue) vaccination relies on attenuation and just does not make use of cross-reactivity. So, no security without attenuation, Jenner did not have to  - take care

Comment: I consider this question of mine as very relevant in respect of coronavirus,.Differentiating immune cells from body cells!. It seems possible, as common cold virus is corona virus just as "corona" is, that both infectiousnous and immunity/ are just the same, i.e. common cold just like corona, vice versa vaccination against corona just like against common cold, that seems possible, thus,  and, counterintuitively, it's "only" the severeness of harm that corona does to target cells that sets it apart from the Common cold.

Comment: Changing a question completely by editing after it was answered it seen as bad practice, as this also does not respect the work of the answer. Please stop this. I will rollback the edits and lock the post.

Comment: If user is not allowed to extensively edit question after it was answered all he may do is delete the question and start anew? If he dares to? What about the consent of those have spent commenting and even answering? As I have done extensive research I feel much brighter on the subject now (I would like shift focus to "bat virus" which is a different species. Answers are correct: ferret virus is same, however bat virae are different species. "Just" let me know if this is too hot a topic for casual writing...no problem to postpone or refrain, to me).

Comment: @Chris I very much revised my question as I felt unable to delete it because - according to the rules -  it had already be answered. What are the option? I may ask the person who answered to withdraw his/her answer, then delete question? I am very keen on putting up any completely changed question, as my question  did not raise any further interest. By the way, difficult to find out if any vote count with this question would vanish too and  go away.

Answer (score 4):

We cannot say if the virus in ferrets gets less or more dangerous than the one which actually circulates in humans. There are two problems with this infection:

- The ferrets can build a reservoir for the virus making it possible for circulation to occur among these animals and re-introduce it into the human population. It may also be possible that the virus jumps into other animals, also enabling transmission.
- It is possible that the virus mutates in the animals (it does this anyways) and changes, so acquired immunity against the original SARS-CoV-2 it will not be present or at least less effective, enabling further infections. This can also render a vaccine directed against a mutated part ineffective.

So far, these things are concerns only, but to avoid them, swift action with the killing of all Danish ferrets has been taken.

About your example with Jenner: He was simply lucky that the cow pox he used for this experiment where close enough to the small pox to generate immunity. For the SARS virus we still talk about the same virus, not a different one.

Comment: I read your answer after having edited my question, and I think it is still valid and good. Again, deleting the question would be all right by me if that's the option you opt for.